# Can I encrypt live volume using DiskCryptor?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, disk-encryption

I am running `Windows Home Premium` Edition.

I downloaded and ran `DiskCryptor`.  OS and Data and everything on drive C:.

I set DiskCryptor to volume C: and clicked Encrypt.  After entering password and the like, I ran Encrypt.  It started encrypting and is now at 2% encrypted as reported by DiskCryptor.

I found it strange that:

- DiskCryptor did not warn me of anything
- it is apparently encrypting live volume.  Is that even safe?  Is that even possible?

What did I get myself into?  Or am I okay and things will work as intended?  I expected to have to unmount the volume and do all that kind of stuff in order to encrypt it properly.

My question is -- will my volume C: be encrypted fine and will I be protected, as in will intended DiskCryptor functionality work?

Comment: It's safest to have a backup before anything like this. But what's happening with your drive? Did it work?

Comment: it worked!  it worked!

Comment: Why did you tag this [truecrypt], when your actual question doesn't mention truecrypt, only diskcryptor?

Comment: there really needs to be a `diskcryptor` tag.  I am taking `truecrypt` tag off for now.  Only tagged it because the audience is/will be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - from direct experience, with no ill effects so far.